# Aggregating text and deleting duplicates with pandas to consolidate a table for reporting

Tags: python, python-2.x, pandas

At work, I use software for analyzing administrative data and daily I generate a CSV that looks like:

```
ReceiptDate,Agent,Project,ControlNum 
6/13/2017 18:02,Markieff,T180222559.P,492 
6/13/2017 18:02,Markieff,T180222559.P,493 
6/13/2017 18:02,Markieff,T180222559.P,494 
6/12/2017 18:01,Markieff,C181224579.N,7240 
6/11/2017 17:43,Marcus,T180046232.P,635 

Exported count: 5,Total items count: 5,
```

but with several hundred entries instead of just four. Sometimes the same Project can have dozens of ControlNums.

I have to report this stuff by e-mail and via updating a couple of spreadsheets and it's a lot more presentable if it's in tables that look like:

```
6/13/2017 18:02 | Markieff | T180222559.P | 494, 493, 492
6/12/2017 18:01 | Markieff | C181224579.N | 7240
6/11/2017 17:43 | Marcus | T180046232.P | 635
```

To that end and to fulfill my New Year's resolution to finally learn how to code a little bit, I've slapped together a script in Python that does that for me.

The script is more than fast enough for my purposes but I always want to get better. The code is below, and my questions follow (though feedback of any kind is welcome):

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', None)

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', skipfooter = 1, engine='python')

# I convert ControlNum to strings for the sake of joining them
df['ControlNum'] = df['ControlNum'].apply(lambda x: str(x))

df = df.sort_values(by=['ReceiptDate', 'Agent', 'Project', 'ControlNum'], ascending = False)

# Marks the entries with a Project that's used more than once
df['HasMultipleControlNums'] = df.duplicated(subset=['Project'], keep = False)

# We don't need to mess with the entries with unique Projects
df_complexprojects = df[df['HasMultipleControlNums'] == True]

# I know C is a bad variable name but I barely understand groupby so I'm not sure
# what a better, more descriptive name would be. Anyway, these two lines join
# together ControlNums that belong to the same project
C = df_complexprojects.groupby(['Project'])['ControlNum'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x))
# This line triggers pandas's SettingWithCopyWarning, which I've muted.
df_complexprojects['ControlNum'] = df_complexprojects['Project'].apply(lambda x: C.get_value(x))

# After joining together ControlNums, we have some identical entries. Bye-bye.
df_complexprojects = df_complexprojects.drop_duplicates(subset='Project', keep='first')

# This step is why df['HasMultipleControlNums'] exists. Is there a better way to
# bring the entries I worked on and the entries I didn't together?
df_final = df_complexprojects.append(df[df['HasMultipleControlNums'] == False], ignore_index = True)

del df_final['HasMultipleControlNums']

# In practice, this script is in a function. The returned dataframe
# is manipulated using Beautiful Soup and win32api (to create Outlook
# e-mails) and Flask (so I can do all of this via a web app with a GUI)
# and archived as an Excel spreadsheet
return df_final
```

Here it is again without the gratuitous comments:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', None)

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', skipfooter = 1, engine='python')

df['ControlNum'] = df['ControlNum'].apply(lambda x: str(x))

df = df.sort_values(by=['ReceiptDate', 'Agent', 'Project', 'ControlNum'], ascending = False)

df['HasMultipleControlNums'] = df.duplicated(subset=['Project'], keep = False)

df_complexprojects = df[df['HasMultipleControlNums'] == True]

C = df_complexprojects.groupby(['Project'])['ControlNum'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x))
df_complexprojects['ControlNum'] = df_complexprojects['Project'].apply(lambda x: C.get_value(x))

df_complexprojects = df_complexprojects.drop_duplicates(subset='Project', keep='first')

df_final = df_complexprojects.append(df[df['HasMultipleControlNums'] == False], ignore_index = True)

del df_final['HasMultipleControlNums']

return def_final
```

1. Is this readable/good style/Pythonic? Without the comments, would anyone understand what I'm doing here? Does it reek of amateurism?
2. Do I need to create df_complexprojects and df_final? Is df['MultipleControlNums'] necessary? Is that SettingWithCopyWarning something I should take more seriously?
3. Is pandas overkill for this? As a novice, would I be better-served learning how to do this with simple data structures? (An earlier version of this used openpyxl and not pandas and it was sooooooooooooo slow)
4. What else should I be asking? I don't know what I don't know.

I apologize if this is too broad/wordy for codereview. I'm new at all of this and am dying for feedback from more experienced folks. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Not relevant directly, but check out this [PyCon 2017 talk about optimizing Pandas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HN5d490_KKk) - might provide some ideas about possible techniques in terms of time/memory optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

So pandas can have a bit of learning curve, but let's go ahead and use `groupby` more like it was intended.  This won't be terribly performant, but it is much fewer lines of code, and thus will optimize programmer time once you are proficient with the techniques.

I think the majority of your code can be reduced to:

#### Code:

```
a_group = df.groupby(['ReceiptDate', 'Agent', 'Project'])
new_df = a_group['ControlNum'].apply(
    lambda x: ','.join(sorted(x.astype(str)))).reset_index()
new_df = new_df.rename(columns={new_df.columns[-1]: 'ControlNum'})
```

#### How?

1. Construct a groupby object.
2. Use `apply()` against the `ControlNum` column in each group to call a function on that column.
3. The result of the `apply` is a series with the groups as an index.  So use reset_index() to get a dataframe.
4. Rename the last column to `ControlNum`

#### Result:

```
       ReceiptDate     Agent       Project   ControlNum
0  6/12/2017 18:01  Markieff  C181224579.N         7240
1  6/13/2017 18:02  Markieff  T180222559.P  492,493,494
```

#### Learning Pandas:

So, in general the crew here (at Code Review) is way more welcoming to newbies than over at Stackoverflow, but...

pandas is extremely well supported at StackOverflow.  I am pretty confident if you had put this code up, with the dataset and expected data, and your explanation that you were confused over the use of groupby(), that you would have gotten an answer (likely from the pandas `A` team, I'm at best the `B` team) in a fairly short period of time.

Welcome to CodeReview. Cheers.